# Christoffel symbol matrix formulation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

Let there exist an arbitrary (2,0)-tensor $T^{ij}$ such that the covariant derivative is defined as $$\nabla_aT^{ij}=\partial_aT^{ij}+\Gamma^i_{ak}T^{kj}+\Gamma^j_{ak}T^{ik}. $$ To define the Christoffel there must exist some metric $g_{ij}.$ The Christoffel symbol defined in terms of the metric connection follows $$\Gamma^i_{ak}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}(\partial_kg_{ma}+\partial_ag_{mk}-\partial_mg_{ak}).$$ Since $k$ is the dummy index in the covariant derivative it will take values $$\Gamma^i_{at},\Gamma^i_{ar},\Gamma^i_{a \theta},\Gamma^i_{a \phi}$$. I know how to represent the Christoffel symbols in matrix form to find out all the different various permutations of indices, like $$\Gamma^t_{ai}=\begin{pmatrix}\Gamma^t_{00}&\Gamma^t_{01}&\Gamma^t_{02}&\Gamma^t_{03}\\\Gamma^t_{10}&\Gamma^t_{11}&\Gamma^t_{12}&\Gamma^t_{13}\\\Gamma^t_{20}&\Gamma^t_{21}&\Gamma^t_{22}&\Gamma^t_{23}\\\Gamma^t_{30}&\Gamma^t_{31}&\Gamma^t_{32}&\Gamma^t_{33}&\end{pmatrix},$$ where the 1st covariant index $a$ represents the row and $i$ the column. If there exists a dummy index in one of the covariant indices like $$\Gamma^i_{ak}$$ where $k$ is the dummy indices and takes values $$\Gamma^i_{at},\Gamma^i_{ar},\Gamma^i_{a \theta}, \Gamma^i_{a \phi}.$$ How would I represent $\Gamma^i_{at}$ in matrix form where t is the index that is fixed and does not represent any row or column? Would the $i$ index be the row index then $a$ the column index or vice versa such that it follows as $$\Gamma^i_{at}=\begin{pmatrix}\Gamma^0_{0t}&\Gamma^0_{1t}&\Gamma^0_{2t}&\Gamma^0_{3t}\\\Gamma^1_{0t}&\Gamma^1_{1t}&\Gamma^1_{2t}&\Gamma^1_{3t}\\\Gamma^2_{0t}&\Gamma^2_{1t}&\Gamma^2_{2t}&\Gamma^2_{3t}\\\Gamma^3_{0t}&\Gamma^3_{1t}&\Gamma^3_{2t}&\Gamma^3_{3t}\end{pmatrix}?$$ Would that be the right idea or would I have to swap the top and bottom indices?

Comment: Use whatever convention you want.

Comment: So the upper index can be represented as a row?

Comment: @aygx There is no definite answer to your question as the operations performed using the symbols, such as index contractions, obviously do not depend on how the individual coefficients are shown on paper. I'm voting to close as opinion-based.